# AWT Choice in a calculator

Tags: java, awt, calculator

I basically don't know how to forward the value I get from a Choice and use it in a equation later on.

I'm building a calculator and I need to have a Choice control with operations and a button that calculates with the operation selected in the Choice.

```
b1 = Calculate button
```

This is the equation I use

```
Double n1 = Double.parseDouble(t1.getText());
Double n2 = Double.parseDouble(t2.getText());
     
 if (e.getSource() == b1) {
    t3.setText(String.valueOf(n1 [here should be the operator selected from the Choice] n2)); }
```

The idea is when clicked on the button Calculate n1 and n2 should perform operation selected in Choice control.

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVayL.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Dqwa.png)

Comment: Prefer to upload everything as text. For images, use this site directly. If the other site goes down your question would be no longer understandable.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Choice.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Choice.html) about Choice. That class offers the methods
[getSelectedItem()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Choice.html#getSelectedItem()) and [getSelectedIndex()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Choice.html#getSelectedIndex()) that you can use in your event listener.

Here is an example:

```
if (e.getSource() == b1) {
    switch(choice.getSelectedIndex()) {
        case 0:
            t3.setText(String.valueOf(n1 + n2));
            break; 
        case 1:
            t3.setText(String.valueOf(n1 - n2));
            break; 
        case 2:
            t3.setText(String.valueOf(n1 * n2));
            break; 
        case 3:
            t3.setText(String.valueOf(n1 / n2));
            break; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how to project the value I get from getSelectedItem to the equation (t3.setText (String.valueOf(n1 [<<<value should be here>>>] n2)

Comment: I added some example code.

Comment: Thank you very much, kind sir!!! :) I knew it's probably an easy solution, the problem is, I tend to overthink stuff... Need to fix that habit.